# Initialization during explicit declaration

Tags: c, global-variables

I was going through following code, but it stuck me that in the following code the `int y=5`, statement is at the end of program while the `main` function also has the return statement so even before reaching the last statement the program control is returned back to compiler so how does this code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int x = 10 ;
int main( )
{
    extern int y;
    printf(“The value of x is %d \n”,x);
    printf(“The value of y is %d”,y);
    return 0;
}

int y=50;
```

Comment: It's a global variable. Note that it's out of `main`'s scope. It's encouraged to place global variables in the beginning of the file, or at least, let them be in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the program carefully.

`int y=50;` in not inside `main()` function scope. It's outside `main()`. It is a global variable, just like `int x = 10 ;`

So, your `main()` is not suppossed to *reach* this statement while in execution. However, to improve readibility, it is de-facto standard to put all your global variable declaration and definitions at the beginning of the file.

Comment: So Sourav is it the definition part that determines the Scope of the variable then.??

Comment: @RohitSaluja yes, what else?

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying everything :)